# Getting the file path from file name in java

Tags: java

To get the file path from file name in directory
I have src/test/resources/datasheets directory.

```
src/test/resources/datasheets
xyz/a1.txt
abc/b1/txt
```

It has many directories again

I need to get the file path If i give the file name
ex : "a1.txt"  I need to get as `src/test/resources/datasheets/xyz/a1.txt`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using so we can see where you might be having difficulty?  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Isn't `abc/b1/txt` supposed to be `abc/b1.txt`?

Comment: Are you running tests from something like `maven`, which defines a directory for test resources as `src/test/resources`?  If so, when running your tests, the resources would get copied into the build directory, and the path to the `a1.txt` resource would actually only be `datasheets/xyz/a1.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Just write a recursive method to check all sub directories. I hope that will work:

```
import java.io.File;

public class PathFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = getPath("a1.txt", "src/test/resources/datasheets");
        System.out.println(path);
    }

    public static String getPath(String fileName, String folder) {
        File directory = new File(folder);

        File[] fileList = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : fileList) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                if(fileName.equals(file.getName())) {
                    return file.getAbsolutePath();
                }
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                String path = getPath(fileName, file.getAbsolutePath());
                if(!path.isEmpty()) {
                    return path;
                }
            }
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This information is easily accessible if you had referred to the [[File docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)].

```
File myDir = File(String pathname);
if(myDir.isDirectory()) {
    File[] contents = myDir.listFiles(); 
}
```

See what your `contents[]` looks like and make necessary modifications.